# Can Thanos pick up Mjolnir after wearing the infinity gauntlet?

Tags: marvel, mjolnir, thanos, the-infinity-gauntlet

I know wearing the Infinity Gauntlet doesn't make Thanos worthy, but seeing that he could alter reality, destroy half of the universe in one go using the gauntlet, (and much more awesome stuff) I assume he kind of has unlimited power. So, could he wield it? Is there any reference to this in the comics or any animated movies/series?

P.S: I am not talking about destroying Mjolnir, just wield it like Thor.

Comment: @CBredlow that's a good theory, but I was thinking about like maybe he could alter the spell. Could he do that?

Comment: The events of *Thor:Ragnarok* seem to suggest no....

Comment: @Skooba if you are talking about breaking it then  but if it's anything else then please elaborate.

Comment: @GirishKulkarni I was. Wasn't sure if you'd actually seen the film yet, so I was trying to funny and sly.

Comment: @Skooba you succeeded. I chuckled. Well done.

Comment: This question is literally: What happens when an irresistible force meets an immovable object?

Comment: For those who moved to close this question, it is not opinion-based. The entire Marvel canon supports the notion that the IG overpowers Odin's worthiness enchantment, and nothing contradicts it. I just have to provide comic-based sources which will take time.

Answer (score 5):

## Yes.

The Infinity Gauntlet grants omnipotence, more than enough power to overcome any enchantment of Odin.

From the Wikipedia article on the [Infinity Gauntlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinity_Gauntlet), the comic story that the MCU is drawing from:

> Each Gem grants its bearer complete mastery over one aspect of the multiverse: Time, Space, Mind, Soul, Reality, and Power. Combined on the Infinity Gauntlet, Thanos is granted omnipresence, omniscience, and omnipotence.

Comment: this doesnt seem to hold true for the MCU where Thanos seems to have powers from the stones but not complete mastery

Comment: This may be true, but still it is speculative at best. Did you find any Comic book reference?